# Limitation of ModelState.IsValid in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, validation, modelstate, validationattribute

I always use `ModelState.IsValid` for check all of my model validation validated correctly in Server Side, but I think there is a limitation to use this. For example I define a `Remote` Validation attribute, but if I disable `javascript` then `ModelState.IsValid` don't check Remote Validation and always return true, Where is the problem? this is a limitation for `ModelState.IsValid` or is my fault? If necessary I can Add all my implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has come around a few times. The answer is: it doesn't validate on the server-side, you have to perform the validation action yourself. See also following SO posts:

- [asp.net mvc 3 serverside remote validation not working on submit through fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547674/asp-net-mvc-3-serverside-remote-validation-not-working-on-submit-through-fiddler)
- [RemoteAttribute validator does not fire server-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393020/remoteattribute-validator-does-not-fire-server-side)

Of course, it would be nice to be able to validate it anyway on the server-side. Luckily some nice guy made an implementation for it. You can find his short blog post: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-mvc-server-side-remote-validation .