# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Nick and Email taken validation (Ajax calls)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

What is the recommended way to handle "Nick / Email taken" AJAX validation in MVC that integrates nicely with validators provided by DataAnnotantion (@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email))? I understand that I would probably have something like this:

```
<input id="email" onBlur="emailTaken();" onchanged="emailTaken();" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function emailTaken() {
        var encodedEmail = enc($("#email").val());
        $.getJSON("/Ajax/EmailTaken/" + encodedEmail, function (data) {
            if (data.res) {
                // all is OK
            } else {
                // TODO: Show Error?
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I already know that on Server I can do ModelState.AddModelError and I am doing it... but I want to know what is recommended way for ClientSide validation? Do I need to invoke some method provided by jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably want to use Remote Validation for this.  It's built-in, so you don't have to do any of your own javascript.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: Only downside is that it won't be executed serverside (cfr. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494168/limitation-of-modelstate-isvalid-in-asp-net-mvc-3/ )

Comment: @Styxxy - True, but neither would his original solution.  He needs to do server side validation as well.

Comment: @Styxxy Thanks for providing link... this is definitely something I will look to automate. And I appreciate your spot-on answer Mystere Man